# Adjust position of panels in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I am told to make a shopping cart website using bootstrap with the images of products positioned in two rows and with three panels in each row
Although here i have coded for only one panel with the image within it,the main problem that I am facing is to adjust the position of panel which is always appearing on the top of the page.
I tried to enclose it in a div with id posi and then tried to position it using  but it didn't work so please help.Further the image is appearing too big so what is  the best method to re-size it so that the image responsiveness remains intact.I also have another question which is written in my code snippet(as a comment) if anybody knows the answer of that kindly help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
  Web page
  </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
   #posi
   {
    position=absolute;
    top=100px;
    right=50px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="posi">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row" >
   <div class="col-md-3 col-md-6" ><!--Although I have used this col-md-3 col-md-6 but I also want to know 
   what happens when we specify two column definitions in a single class like this-->
    <div class="panel panel-default" >
     <div class="panel-heading panel-primary">
      Iphone 6
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <img src="http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4711/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone6/plus/iphone6-plus-box-gold-2014?wid=478&hei=595&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1411520675923" class="img-responsive" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "appearing on the top of the page": what does this mean? Where is it supposed to be positioned, it's the first and only element on the page.

Comment: i actually want to directly position it at top-100px and right-50px but it is not working

Comment: although I enclosed it in the div posi added postion in style tag but it is not working so what is the problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `position` for `top` to take effect.

```css
body,
html {
  background: grey;
}
#wrapper {
  top: 100px;
  right: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading panel-primary">Iphone 6</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <img src="http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4711/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone6/plus/iphone6-plus-box-gold-2014?wid=478&hei=595&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1411520675923"
            class="img-responsive" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading panel-primary">Iphone 6</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <img src="http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4711/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone6/plus/iphone6-plus-box-gold-2014?wid=478&hei=595&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1411520675923"
            class="img-responsive" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading panel-primary">Iphone 6</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <img src="http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4711/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone6/plus/iphone6-plus-box-gold-2014?wid=478&hei=595&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1411520675923"
            class="img-responsive" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading panel-primary">Iphone 6</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <img src="http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4711/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone6/plus/iphone6-plus-box-gold-2014?wid=478&hei=595&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1411520675923"
            class="img-responsive" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading panel-primary">Iphone 6</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <img src="http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4711/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone6/plus/iphone6-plus-box-gold-2014?wid=478&hei=595&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1411520675923"
            class="img-responsive" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading panel-primary">Iphone 6</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <img src="http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4711/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone6/plus/iphone6-plus-box-gold-2014?wid=478&hei=595&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1411520675923"
            class="img-responsive" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok got it,I had one more question that is how to set the gap between each of the columns?

Comment: If you want to change that you'll have to override the column gutter. You can see the defaults at http://getbootstrap.com/css/ then scroll down to Grid Options.